# how to add loop and shuffle in player

Tags: android

how to add loop and shuffle in android.i add but it was not working.please solve this issue and help me.following is my code details.in i want to add repeat and shuffle option and i did some coding as follows

```
                @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.player);
    final AudioManager audioManager = (AudioManager)getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
    int maxVolume = audioManager.getStreamMaxVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
    int curVolume = audioManager.getStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
      // MusicPlayerActivity.mpObject.setOnCompletionListener(this);
       settings=(Button)findViewById(R.id.settings);

       hide=(Button)findViewById(R.id.hide);
       loop=(ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.btnRepeat);
       shuffle=(ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.btnShuffle);
       time_duration=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.time_duration);
       total_time_duration=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.total_time_duration);


       volumebar=(SeekBar)findViewById(R.id.volbar);
      volumebar.setMax(maxVolume);
       volumebar.setProgress(curVolume);
       volumebar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
           @Override
           public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar arg0) {
           }

           @Override
           public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar arg0) {
           }

           @Override
           public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar arg0, int arg1, boolean arg2) {

               System.out.println("changing volumes.....");
               audioManager.setStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, arg1, 0);
           }
       });

      seekBar = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.seekBar);
    seekBar.setMax(300);
    seekBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(this);

    play=(ImageView) findViewById(R.id.player_play_pause_image);
    settings.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Intent i=new Intent(MusicPlayerActivity.this,Settings.class);
            startActivity(i);
        }
    });
    mBinder = new ServiceBinder(this);
    mBinder.bindService(new ServiceBinderDelegate() {

        @Override
        public void onIsBound() {
            togglePlay(Songs.current_track);

        }
    });
     loop.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {

                if(isRepeat){
                    isRepeat = false;
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Repeat is OFF", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    loop.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
                }else{
                    // make repeat to true
                    isRepeat = true;
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Repeat is ON", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    // make shuffle to false
                    isShuffle = false;
                    loop.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
                    shuffle.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
                }
            }
        });

    linearplayerlayout=(LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.playerlayout);

      utils = new Utilities();

      mIndex=Songs.current_track;
     StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build(); StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
    //   add=(Button)findViewById(R.id.add);


     hide.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        //  clear_music();
            //finish();
            Songs.current_track=mIndex;
            moveTaskToBack (true);
        }
    });


    seekBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new OnSeekBarChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
            if (mIsTrackLoaded)
                mBinder.getService().seek((float) seekBar.getProgress() / seekBar.getMax());
        }

        @Override
        public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {

        }
    });

    shuffle.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            if(isShuffle){
                isShuffle = false;
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Shuffle is OFF", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                shuffle.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
            }else{
                // make repeat to true
                isShuffle= true;
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Shuffle is ON", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                // make shuffle to false
                isRepeat = false;
                shuffle.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
                loop.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
            }
        }
    });


    findViewById(R.id.player_prev).setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            playPrev();
        }
    });

    findViewById(R.id.player_next).setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            playNext();
        }
    });

    findViewById(R.id.player_play_pause).setOnClickListener(

    new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            System.out.println("TOGGLE PLAY");
            togglePlay(mIndex);
        }
    });



}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can quickly add songs to your queue when browsing your library on ... the Menu icon to add music to your queue.

Use the buttons on the Now Playing bar at the bottom of the screen to control playback, shuffle songs, or repeat songs.

Here's a quick reference guide to the Now Playing screen. ... the previous or next track; How to reorder the play queue; How to repeat or shuffle the play queue; Overflow menu ... Add to Play Queue: Place this item at the end of the play queue. **[DB Product Review](http://dbproductreview.yolasite.com/blog.php)**

Comment: hi i add repeat and shuffle but it is not working please check